# SharePoint installation using one-account method

Tags: 2010, 2013, security, service-account

please help me with one hard task. I am not able to convince some admins and neither whole companies that installing & using SharePoint by using one (local) account method is against all best practices, against product information and in defiance of common sense. Even if I am using TechNet articles as references like [this one](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14500.sharepoint-2013-service-accounts.aspx) or [this one](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262502%28v=office.14%29.aspx), blog articles and do the right installations for demo, I have no luck from many reasons. (Probably they need to hear it from someone more experienced than me or from huge amount of people. And no, I do not want to give up this fight). Often they do not see it as threat simply because they cannot think about consequences.

Can you please help me to build a list of consequences for such type of installations? Your experience what is impossible to use or do if you choose such kind of installation? For SP 2010 & SP 2013 as well.

Thank you.

Comment: It is a long-term fight, I know about 36 farms or so, instaled by this method at this time. Just the situation from yesterday forced me to write this post - some developer told me that I must reinstall whole healthy farm from scratch using one-super-user-account in order to use their application, otherwise it will not work...

Answer (score 0):

looks like your fighting a loosing battle!

Having one account for all is very bad to say the least! your giving way too much access not only to services but also to SQL server!! talk about unsecure!

If something goes wrong with that account then everything is going to go wrong.

This will fail compliance with in any organisation! If your company wants to be recognised for security and uptime than forget it!

some more pointers here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/modonovan/archive/2009/09/16/most-common-issue-with-sharepoint-installations-service-account-misuse.aspx